# Transfer existent password in md5 format to apache .htpasswd

Tags: apache, encryption, mantis

I have installed Mantis bugtracking system in an intranet and now I want to also copy the those users with their passwords to an Apache .htpasswd file for another intranet site, so they can login without need to come to my console and re-type their passwords. I understand that Mantis stores passwords using md5 algorithm but Apache uses a modified version (apr1). Is there any way to convert from md5 to apr1?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31212471/1145196

Comment: I think that the related post is not applicable since it tries to sort out by configuring nginx, but I'm using Apache.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that :), but that might end up being the only solution...

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot convert from one hashing algorithm to another, as it is not possible to recreate the original text from the hash.

One way to do this may be to use mod_auth_mysql to authenticate directly against the mantis user table, but I haven't ever done this myself, so I cannot guarantee that mod_auth_mysql can be configured for the exact hashing and table layout that mantis uses.